# Create currency input with superscript in flutter

Tags: flutter, input, format, currency, superscript

I need make a flutter currency input like this in image

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3ZPH.jpg)

I have been looking for some library that helps me with this, but didnt found anyone.

Please note that symbol and decimals are like superscript.

Any idea can help me. Thanks a lot!

I tried to get the input with symbol and decimals in superscript, but my efforts were unsuccesful.